# OnePage checkout by opened sections

Tags: magento-1.8, onepage-checkout

In my onepage checkout I want to open all sections by default. When customer will open onepage checkout page, already could to see shipping methods and payment methods for default billing and shipping addresses. 
So I think it will possible if all time I did trigger click on "continue" buttons. But this method I don't like.

[image]

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is what you want to do? You see, those sections are hidden for a good reason as they usually depend on previous elements -- to choose shipping method you must usually choose a country first.

However, if you still feel like you absolutely need to display all them steps regardless of my warning, then check out `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage.phtml` there's code that adds `display: none;` to (still) closed block elements. Remove the style and they should be all visible right from the start. But as I mentioned -- be warned of side effects.